# Error accumulation

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

Assume that $a_j\leq u$ and $p_j\in\{-1,+1\}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$ and that $nu<1$ where $u:=2^{-t-1}$. Show that following is true:
$$\prod^{n}_{j=1}(1+a_j)^{p_j}=1+\theta_n$$ 
where $|\theta(n)|\leq\gamma_n$ for which it is true that $\gamma_n:=\frac{nu}{1-nu}$

This is question from [here](https://books.google.pl/books?id=5tv3HdF-0N8C) (p. 63), but unfortunately it's given without a proof.

I tried to split that lemma into two parts, where all $a_k$ have their $p_k$ with value of 1 and all $a_l$ have $p_l$ of -1, but I don't see what's next.

Comment: It is not quite correct, that there is no proof. 
You are directed to problem 3.1 and the answer to this 
gives a complete proof by induction.

Comment: @gammatester: I thought that "Problem 3.1" is "Prove lemma 3.1". Where is it?

Comment: Where is what? Correct me if I am wrong, but your problem **is** Lemma 3.1 with the replacements $i \rightarrow j,\; \delta_i \rightarrow a_i, \;  \rho_i \rightarrow p_i$. The proof is in Appendix A, Solutions to Problems, p.535.